# AngularJS directive to enable/disable all children elements (a, button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-directive

Consider the following HTML

```
<div userLevel="100">
    <a href="/someSite"></a>//should be disabled
    <button type="button">Click me</button>//should be disabled
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="true">Can't click me</button>//maybe already disabled
</div>
```

When my current user level is < 100 all child elements that are either a  link or a button should be disabled. This can be done by adding classname and attribute `"disabled"` (according to Bootstrap 3).

```
$element.find("a, button").toggleClass("disabled", true).prop("disabled", true);
```

But how could I handle child elements, that have been disabled already? How could I handle `ng-disabled` directives on child elements, that depend on anything else but the user level? When enabling I have to remove the disabled class/attr from the elements that have been disabled by my directive only, leaving other disabled elements as they are. How could I achieve this?

This is what I have so far:

```
.directive("userLevel", [
    "userService",
    function ($USER) {
        return {
            restrict : "A",
            scope : true,
            link : function ($scope, $element, $attr) {

                var m_evtNS = ".userLevel",

                    //the user level needed to access children
                    m_RequiredUserLevel = $scope.$eval($attr["userLevel"]),

                    /**
                     *
                     * @param {Boolean} disable
                     */
                    disable = function (disable) {
                        //remove evt listener and toggle children class/attr
                        $element
                            .off(m_evtNS)
                            .find("a, button")
                            .toggleClass("disabled", disable)
                            .prop("disabled", disable);

                        //show login dialog when clicking on disabled elements
                        if (disable) {
                            $element.on("click" + m_evtNS, function () {
                                $USER.showLoginDialog();
                            });
                        }
                    };

                //watch for changes of the current user level (login/logout)
                $scope.$watch(function () {
                   return $USER.CurrentUser.level;
                }, function (userLevel) {
                   disable(userLevel < m_RequiredUserLevel);
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```

Comment: You can use multiple conditions like `ng-disabled="someVariable || userLevel < 100"`

Comment: @devqon: I could do this. Anyway I still need a directive to show the loginDialog when clicking on a disabled element. I'm also thinking of a special title popup that tells the user that he needs to login to enable these elements.